# Rails check_box_tag params does not appear the first POST the second time they are available in the params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Newbie with RoR, who is going crazy!

When I tick a couple of the check_boxes and Click on the Submit button. The checked boxes (array of values) are NOT available in the Param. The page then redirects back to itself. When I then do the same thing again(tick a couple of check_boxes and click Submit), then the checked boxes are available in the params and I can save them. What is going wrong the first time around and how can I fix it. What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks alot!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
 <%= form_for(@user, url: registration_path(@user), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <%= devise_error_messages! %>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <p><%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></p>
</div>

<!-- <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
  <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "New password confirmation"  %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(to confirm changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div> -->


<%= form_for (@user.musician) do |musician_form| %>
  <%= musician_form.label "Naam" %>
  <p><%= musician_form.text_field :name %></p>

  <%= musician_form.label "Wat is je woonplaats?" %>
  <p><%= musician_form.text_field :city %></p>

  <%= musician_form.label "In welke Provincie woon je?" %><br>
  <%= musician_form.select :province_id, Province.all.collect{|t| [t.description, t.id]}, { :include_blank => false } %><br><br>

  <%= musician_form.label "Wat is je geboortedatum?" %>
  <p><%= musician_form.date_select :birthday %></p>

  <%= musician_form.label "Beschrijving" %><br>
  <%= musician_form.text_area :description, class: "form-control", size: "40x5" %>

<div class="actions">
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Wijzigingen opslaan", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<b>Welk type muzikant ben je?</b><br><br>

 <% for musician_type in MusicianType.all %>
  <div>
   <%= check_box_tag "musician[musician_type_ids][]", musician_type.id, @user.musician.musician_types.include?(musician_type) %>
  <%= musician_type.description %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<br>
<b>In welke genre(s) ben je geinteresseerd?</b><br><br>
<% for genre in Genre.all %>
  <div>
   <%= check_box_tag "musician[genre_ids][]", genre.id, @user.musician.genres.include?(genre) %>
   <%= genre.description %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
 <br>

   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p>Niet tevreden? <%= button_to "Account verwijderen", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Weet je zeker dat je je account en bijbehorende band(s) en vacature(s) wilt verwijderen? Het account kan niet meer worden teruggehaald!" }, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %></p>
</div>
```

And here is part of my controller code:

```
def edit
 @user = User.find(current_user.id)
end

def update
  account_update_params =     devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)

  params[:musician][:musician_type_ids] ||= []
  params[:musician][:genre_ids] ||= []

# unless params[:musician][:musician_type_ids].present?
#   params[:musician][:musician_type_ids] = []
#   logger.info "DEBUG INFO: PARAM IS EMPTY #{@musician}"
# end
#
# unless params[:musician][:genre_ids].present?
#   params[:musician][:genre_ids]  = []
# end

@musician = current_user.musician
@musician.update(musician_params)

if needs_password?
  successfully_updated = @user.update_with_password(account_update_params)
else
  account_update_params.delete('password')
  account_update_params.delete('password_confirmation')
  account_update_params.delete('current_password')
  successfully_updated = @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
end

if successfully_updated
  set_flash_message :notice, :updated
  sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
else
  render 'edit'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation at apidock:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

in the comments:

```
<% @roles.each do |role| %>
  <li>
    <%= check_box_tag 'role_ids[]', role.id -%>
    <%= h role.name -%>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Thus, if you want to permit genre_ids you'd have to write:

```
<%= check_box_tag "genre_ids[]", genre.id, @user.musician.genres.include?(genre) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, but it didn't fix the problem. Same thing happens. First time submitting contains No genre_ids[]. Second time submitting does contain the genre_ids[]. So I do not understand why the parameters are not submitted the first time.

Comment: Here the log first without the parameters then with:

Comment: Started PATCH "/users" for ::1 at 2016-03-08 12:26:15 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L74iqhNLvORfxuNb381nZjgL6CEQW14ScbtqnBgmnhUyTIBo0LI3VvuZnaLNQLqsrBVTpkrvnltjgljG4c+7JQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"alex@alex.nl"}, "musician"=>{"name"=>"Alexander", "city"=>"Voorburg", "province_id"=>"1", "birthday(1i)"=>"1972", "birthday(2i)"=>"6", "birthday(3i)"=>"11", "description"=>"Description musician 1\r\nregel 2\r\nregel 3"}, "commit"=>"Wijzigingen opslaan"}

Comment: Started PATCH "/users" for ::1 at 2016-03-08 12:27:21 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zhhnuNwDgoEnmT/FbVJjeHT5JdX30r+Wv5PZzVlHzNrT6sV6H/oJM4PGQTx/376y4OeeUq1mf9+tquuXoK7p6g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"alex@alex.nl"}, "musician"=>{"name"=>"Alexander", "city"=>"Voorburg", "province_id"=>"1", "birthday(1i)"=>"1972", "birthday(2i)"=>"6", "birthday(3i)"=>"11", "description"=>"Description musician 1\r\nregel 2\r\nregel 3"}, "commit"=>"Wijzigingen opslaan", "genre_ids"=>["1", "2"]}

Comment: And maybe important to mention the check_boxes are part of a nested form